Setting the default screen in React Navigation
I defined "initialRouteName" in the code, but it does not refer to the default, it correctly displays the screens in the index, and really only when I pass the "login" is the only way it displays it,
Maybe I missed something here?
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Index" component={Index} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
        
  );

I downloaded the code in the index file (this file is used as a dashboard)
that the navigation was directly from the "login screen" by an arrow function to the "Home screen"
const handleLogin = () => {
        console.log('Login with username and email');
        navigation.navigate('Home');
        
      };
    ```

The function will do anyway, but I tried to check if I have a problem with the index

And still the situation remains the same, he shows me the "Home screen" (only without dashboard)


Where is the home screen in the stack?

Try the below
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {
return (
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Login">
<Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login}/>
  <Stack.Screen name="Index" component={Index}/>
 </Stack.Navigator>
 );
 }

 const app = () =>{
 return (
 <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack/>
 </NavigationContainer>
    
 );

